# How to share build failure reason of azure devops pipeline through a mail?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-pipelines

*I am working on build pipelines and i felt that i should be able to get a notification on why exactly my build failed when there is build failure(i.e, which task failed and reason for it ). Right now we will only get a mail which just gives build status whether its is succeded, failure or partial succeded.
I was expecting some of you guys might have came across this thought and succeded in implementing it.Any references to that would be much appriciated.*
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Sai, Does my answer help, any update here? Please check it and kindly let me know the result. Thank you.

Comment: Yes and thanks for your reply.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If it works, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Devops does not support that feature. You may add your request here: [Azure DevOps (formerly Visual Studio Team Services)](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion).

In addition, you could use Rest API: [Builds - Get Build Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20logs?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) and [Builds - Get Build Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20log?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get detailed logs, and install this 3rd-extension: [Send Email](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask) in organization and then use it to send email which attaching the logs from failed build to get detailed notification.